# Android Studio gradle error after importing additional library - smack

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a strange error on what I can't find an answer to.

After doing some imports on my class (code below)

```
    package info.zajacmp3.servercommunication;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

/**
 * Created by Mateusz on 04.06.13.
 */
public class ServerCommunication {



    public static boolean isSendableOverInternet(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get and gradle error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':PPMMessenger:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

When I run a stacktrace it tells me nothing... Cause there is nothing tracing to my code.

Here is a stacktrace:

```
* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'compileDebug' not found in ro
ot project 'Mateusz'.
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(Com
mandLineTaskParser.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.doSele
ct(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:65)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.config
ure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.co
nfigure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(Defau
ltTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter
.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:155)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions
.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.368 secs
```

Any help appreciated. I don't see anything here that could help me solve this on my own.

Comment: TaskSelectionException is thrown when the tasks to execute cannot be selected due to some user input problem.

Comment: actually there is not task to execute at all. I just do an import. When I delete this import everything is normally running. Why is that? @ChintanRathod

Comment: no idea my friend. I didn't face such.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem, I needed to add my custom jar library to the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    ADD FILE HERE   
}
```